# what is "TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_HOME"?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is "TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_HOME"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254488/what-is-%22top_dir_your_catkin_home%22?/) by [wenlihua](https://answers.ros.org/users/29340/wenlihua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would have been nice if you'd included a link to wherever you saw that.

Searching, it appears this is something that is used in some PCL tutorials ([wiki/pcl/Tutorials/groovy/How to use a PCL tutorial in ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials/groovy) fi), like so:

```
$ cd %TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_HOME%
$ catkin_make
```

The first line basically instructs you to `cd` into the root of your Catkin workspace. That would be `$HOME/catkin_ws` if you followed any of the Catkin tutorials (but could really be anywhere obviously).

Btw: if the tutorial I linked above is really one that you are following, then note that it is rather outdated. Groovy was EOLed quite some time ago and PCL is not longer a ROS package, but a system dependency.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
See #q79236 for what is basically a duplicate.

**Comment by [wenlihua](https://answers.ros.org/users/29340/wenlihua/) on 2017-02-12**:
thanks so much! i just follow the http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials. my catkin workspace is home/lihua/my_pcl_tutorial. but when i cd to there, i got an error.